# Having trouble to select an image on the canvas

Tags: image, html, canvas, edit

I'm creating a drawing app using HTML5 canvas and JS. I allow user to upload a picture and use `context.drawImage();` to draw it on the canvas. But when I try to edit the picture, I failed. What should I do if I want to use mouse (keyboard, or anything) to drag and scale the picture on the canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For This purpose that includes movement, scaling, resizing , transposition etc. of images on the canvas element of HTML5 you could use **http://fabricjs.com/** (fabric.js) . This javascript library gives u full support and is applicable in most of the modern browsers. Just go through it and u would be able to do all of the mentioned activities. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah， this is what I want, although it may take me some time to learn how to use it. Thank you very much!